# Android Google Maps not showing in signed apk V2

Tags: android, google-maps

My Android app works fine on device without signing but Once I export signed apk file maps no more render 
Do we need to create new API key for release even with V2 if yes please suggest any link that I should follow to create release API key

Comment: Yes, you need a different one. See here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978270/after-exporting-apk-the-google-maps-do-not-show-in-application-why-does-it-happ/16978361#16978361). You can get it from here (https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

Comment: @KenWolf the link given by you is for V1 not v2

Comment: you still need 2 keys

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need a separate API key for your release signing key. The only thing you need to do, is adding SHA of release key on [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), so you have two lines there instead of one:

```
D3:49:EF:3D:0E:...:D5:5F:59:46:11:C1:85;pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo
C1:3A:96:3E:F8:...:4D:F1:52:77:D0:01:0E;pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo
```

Comment: How to get sha of release key ?

Comment: I have replaced my debug.keystore SHA with the one created for release. So API key remains same. Will it create any issue?

Comment: +1 it's works @abdul when i signed my apk, at last finish page show my fingerprints i.e SHA1 its  release key SHA1

Answer (score 2):

@MaciejGórski is correct. Below is small details to it.

In the Google Api console, where we have created the API KEY we have an option to add multiple finger prints to the same key. What I did was adding two SHA1 finger print for my debug keystore and release keystore and the same API key worked for me.

Note the below is for Ubuntu specifically:

1. Get SHA1 for the debug using the below command

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
   ```
2. For getting SHA1 for release the command changes to

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore /home/atul/Desktop/Learnings/Projects/TestApp/keystore.jks -alias test -storepass password -keypass password
   ```

where

`/home/atul/Desktop/Learnings/Projects/TestApp/keystore.jks` is the path where my keystore file for the signed apk is present

`test` is the key alias name used while genrating the signed key store

and `password` is the password used while signing the apk

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have release key in your **"google_maps_api.xml"** file in release folder,

Go to you **app > app > src > release > res > values > google_maps_api.xml
and put your generated key in "google_maps_key" string .**

somthing like this: 
 AIzaSyC3I-3mVulW2TNw_vmil_wGdNj11w5rrFg

its work for me :)