# Google map not showing when make signed apk

Tags: android, google-maps

In my project google map showing and everything working fine when i run code directly from eclipse or android studio, but map showing white screen when i make a signed apk and install my device.

Have anyone idea what can be the issue ?

Comment: chnage your debug map key to release map key

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027772/android-google-maps-not-showing-in-signed-apk-v2

Comment: Issue is all about MAP API Key...

Comment: @ ZygoteInit, currently i am working on another task, and will return soon, i will accept your ans if found usefull.

Comment: @Y.S. another developer working on this project. may i back on it after some time

Comment: @Y.S. yes sure, lets see, when i will work on this.

Comment: where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Comment: problem solved, i manually generate sha1 key and generate a new API Key for release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a signed APK, you have to generate a new API key for the Google Map and update it in the API console. The API key used with the debug APK will not work.

Check your logcat, it probably shows an `Authorization Failure` message.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate signed apk, at last step you get a SHA1 key.copy this key and go to google api console,click API and Auth on left side of screen ->Credential ->create new key->Android Key-> paste SHA1 key that you copied from apk generation screen and after SHA1 key place samicolon";" and your app package name.
It will generate new api key,use it in manifest and run your app.it will display your map.

Comment: **at last step you get a SHA1 key** did not find SHA1 key in last step. i am using android studio

Comment: ok i dont have idea about android studio,are you getting SHA1 key during signing apk?

Comment: see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268520/generate-signed-apk-android-studio generate signed apk using link and it will give you sha1 key.

Comment: No, event i also searching for this key in android studio :-(

Comment: you have to generate through command lind.check above comment