# Google Map not showing with signed APK

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am working on google maps in android . google map is opening by using debug.keystore on my local system but issue is that when i build signed apk then google map not show.however i have also generate SHA1 key from my app keystore then generate new api key but still google map not showing please help as soon as possible

Comment: have you tried app in another devices?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I also put same question, check if any answer is useful.
[Click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983405/google-map-not-showing-when-make-signed-apk?noredirect=1#comment46469803_28983405

Comment: yes i have tried app on different devices but still same issue

Answer (score 1):

From [google docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> In release mode, you sign your app with your own certificate:
>
> Create a keystore. A keystore is a binary file that contains a set of
>   private keys. You must keep your keystore in a safe and secure place.
>
> Create a private key. A private key represents the entity to be
>   identified with the app, such as a person or a company.

So you don't have to generate a new api key. Just generate a new SHA1 for your private key file. After that you have to add it's SHA1 hash into google maps android api section that you have already generated a api key from [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Because you shouldn't change your manifest file for 2 api keys. Just you have to add SHA1 hashes for both keys. *(debug.keystore and your own key file)*

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Sorry for bad censor  :)

Comment: i have also changed in manifest file my google map api key but its not working

Comment: I regenerate Api key from google developer console with my keystore SHA1 and replace API key in manifest file

Comment: As i said you shouldn't change your manifest file you have to use same key that you generated for debug.keystore and your key file. I put a screenshot that how my section looks like.

Comment: I try this i create new project and then i generate new google maps API key with debug.keystore and my own keystore file but still map not showing

Comment: Key for Android apps (with certificates)
API key: 
AIzaSyAYC2He_DMFqf_sD8ONEc61tBVsnkgnyiM
Android apps: 
B0:7E:13:03:A1:DA:CD:0A:A7:20:25:E5:10:02:E7:59:66:96:96:6D;honey.finalmaptest
D5:FA:9B:43:27:5B:47:DD:63:7F:51:5E:84:59:76:6D:37:28:44:E6;honey.finalmaptest
Activated on: Mar 25, 2015 1:07 AM
Activated by: malikrashidabbas@gmail.com – you

Comment: how can i see logcat. because my app  is downloaded from play store

Comment: when i generate API key by using both debug.keystore and my own app release keystore its works on dubugging mode but not working on signing mode when i build signed apk

Comment: are u adding these keys line by line ? or with a white space ? You have to press ENTER after you type your key into google dev console to type other

Comment: yes i adding these keys line by line first write debug.keystore SHA1 and press ENTER then write my own release key SHA1 but still not working

Comment: By using this key google map working perfectly but when i generate signed apk and install on my device then google map not showing .

Comment: i'm pretty sure your release.keystore file and your generated SHA1's are not compatible.

Comment: then please tell me how can i test that my release.keystore file and SHA1,s are compatible or not? if a send u my release.keystore can u tell me the compatible SHA1 with my release key

Comment: Are you making your SHA1 by following rules as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android

Comment: yes i am using android studio and i am following same steps for making SHA1 . first i go to Build then click on Generate Signed apk a dialog window is open then i copy keystore path from dialog window and paste it to command prompt then generate SHA1