# google map API not displayed when export APK

Tags: android, gmail, export, apk, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi I have a problem with **Google Map API V2** does not appear when I export my project *.apk*.
In fact when I do my test sending my Eclipse project via USB everything works, the map is displayed. If I export the project *.apk* to send to a friend via **Gmail** and **Google Map API V2** is not displayed.

I think this is a problem when exporting but I can not solve it.
If you have answers thank you in advance.

Comment: generate another public key and try.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978270/after-exporting-apk-the-google-maps-do-not-show-in-application-why-does-it-happ) one

Answer (score 0):

When exporting your app, in the final step the adt(eclipse) shows you the SHA1 key that would be used. Use that SHA1 key value for generating a new google maps api key. Worked for me.

Comment: Could you expain the process of adding that SHA1 key to your google developer account?

Comment: Login through your gmail account. Now search google developer console, open the first link. now create a new project and under the left menu option "APIs and auth" open APIs. From that select the API you want and then enable it. Now under the same menu there is an option  Credentials. In that menu generate an android key, Enter the same key in your project and the maps will show @AnubianNoob