# I have a query reguarding publishing android game in google play?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-developers-console

I know how to **publish** an normal application in (Google Play Developer Console). I want to know how to publish a **game** in (Google Play Developer Console) which is implementing **Game Services**. My game application is running well and Game Service is working properly.But now I am confused about debug **sha1 debug key and sha1 release key.**
and do I have to linked my game with both debug and release sha1 keys?

Answer (score 0):

I have provided details for generating and specifying the release version of the SHA1 fingerprint in this post: [Getting Android Google Map v2 working in release version by generating SHA1 fingerprint for API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351357/getting-android-google-map-v2-working-in-release-version-by-generating-sha1-fing/27351358#27351358)

Comment: but this if for google maps i am asking about android games

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to release certificate and debug certificate which you need to keep.

> You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate
>   fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint. Make
>   sure to use the same package name for both. This allows Google Play
>   games services to recognize calls from your linked APKs that are
>   signed with either certificate. For more information about certificate
>   signing for Android, see [Signing Your
>   Application](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html).

When all is setup, move to [Testing and Publishing Game Changes](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub).