# Google Map not working in Released apk

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am creating an android app using Google Maps Api v2 targeted for Android Api 16+ compiled using Api 23.

I am having a strange problem. When I tested the app on my phone; installing through Studio's Run button, It work perfectly fine, but when I released an APK and installed the app from the APK on my phone, map does not work. Only a dark grey color loads in the map fragment. I am using the default template provided by the AndroidStudio to create the Map. Please, let me know if you require more details to answer my question.

Thanks in advance,
Abhishek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the API key from separate resources file generated by Studio to Manifest file.

Thank you  [@Florence Herrou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778713/android-google-map-v2-not-showing-map-for-release-apk)  for your answer.