# google maps not working in release version when it was added SHA1 release certificate

Tags: android, google-maps

google maps not working in release version when it was added SHA1 release certificate to console developer.

i was try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158256/google-map-not-working-in-released-apk) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867876/android-sha1-release-keystore-not-working-with-google-maps) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351357/getting-android-google-map-v2-working-in-release-version-by-generating-sha1-fing) but all not work for me

maybe have another answer for this question?

Comment: Can you please share encountered error/s that appears in the logs?

Comment: there's no error just maps not showing